# concatenation of a variable with a string using `.` operator

Tags: php

I am trying to generate an image using php (based on a form received value). Am aware that $_POST received value should be concatenated using dot `.` in order to make the correct image file (means $data.jpeg). BUt image is not generated even after using the `\` character. When i use the hard coding (ie, directly specifying image name with .jpeg extension), image is generated.

Please suggest a solution how to generate an image using

I am attaching the php code below,

```
<?php $data = $_POST['id'] ?>
<?php $data=$data.jpeg ?>

<img src="$data">;             

<?php
```

Comment: You need `. ".jpeg"` since `.jpeg` needs to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

`$data.jpeg` is going to concatenate `$data` with the *constant* `jpeg` (which will default to being the string `"jpeg"`, so you aren't going to have the `.` in the output.

Use a string instead:

```
$data = $data . ".jpeg";
```

Or put the `.jpeg` part in your template:

```
<img src="<?php echo $data; ?>.jpeg">
```

Either way, don't forget to run user input through `htmlspecialchars` so you don't open  yourself up to XSS attacks, and remember to include an appropriate `alt` attribute on your imges.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put ".jpeg" as a string, and concatenate this to your $data var :

```
<?php $data = $_POST['id'] ?>
<?php $data2=$data.".jpeg" ?>

<img src="tree1.jpeg">             

<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should be like.

```
<?php 
    $data = $_POST['id']; 
    $data = $data. ".jpeg"; 
?>

<img src="<?php echo $data; ?>" />
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

i faced same problem when i was new to php. if you are fetching name of images from databse Problem can be your file name may be too long .

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this..

```
<?php $data = $_POST['id'];
     $data=$data.".jpeg"; 
 ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $data;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "<img src='".$_POST['img'].".jpg'>";
}?>

<form method="post" >
<input type="text" name="img"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

this is the code similar to yours and works perfectly